# Pass value between components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Trying to make a todo list, which allows user and click add to add item, but failed miserably.

https://jsfiddle.net/nc84n7px/2

I'm lost how to pass data from `TodoInput` to `Todo_list` via props.

```
    var TodoInput = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
    <div>
     <input type="text" />
     <button onClick={this.props.addItem}>Add</button>
     </div>
    );
  }
});

var Todo_list = React.createClass({
  getInitialState(){
    return { items:[]}
  },
  addItem(items){
  this.setState(this.state.items.push(item))
  },
  render() {
    return (
    <div>
     <li>{this.state.items}</li>
     </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
  <TodoInput />
  <Todo_list />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Comment: Take a look to redux ;) http://redux.js.org/

Comment: @SteevePitis why? u need redux to do a todo list app?

Comment: You can do without, but it's easier ;) btw you have this to understand how react works https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/tree/gh-pages/examples/react

Comment: I don't need a full todo app with edit and delete, can you show me how to add new item when user clicked add? that is it.

Comment: @SteevePitis your comment is worthless, I'm stuck that;s why I need help.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ncq9xkhg/ I have updated your fiddle. Is that you want ?

Comment: @SteevePitis ok I got it. seems like it's impossible to do rendering for 2 components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your can't pass value between two 'sibling' components as presented in your code:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <TodoInput />
    <Todo_list />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

But you can achieve this in two ways:

**1st Option**: including `<TodoInput />` in the the `render()` method of the `<Todo_list />`. Here is an example of how you can approach this: https://jsfiddle.net/petebere/0wqLhaqu/

**2nd Option**: rendering `<TodoInput />` and `<Todo_list />` inside a parent component. The parent component would be responsible for maintaining state and passing values between `<TodoInput />` and `<Todo_list />`.

Option 1 code:

```
var TodoInput = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
        userInput: ''
    };
  },

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
        userInput: event.target.value
    });
  },

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.addItem(this.state.userInput);
    this.setState({
        userInput: ''
    });
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <input type="text"
                     onChange={this.handleChange}
                     value={this.state.userInput} />
        <input type="submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
});

var Todo_list = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
        items: []
    };
  },

  addItem(item) {
    this.setState({
        items: this.state.items.concat(item)
    });
  },

  render() {
    const renderTodos = this.state.items.map((item, index) => {
        return <li key={index}>{item}</li>;
    });

    return (
      <div>
         <TodoInput addItem={this.addItem} />
         {renderTodos}
      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Todo_list  />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Comment: I've just updated the link to JSFiddle. Also, I've added a feature where the input field is cleared when submit button is clicked. The demo uses plain React JS (no redux). Do you need help understanding what is going on in the code?

Comment: I want to reuse the input, I know putting inputComponent within the list is easy, my question is how to pass value btw multiple components

Comment: Would you like to have for example, 3 input fields and only 1 submit button? Then when the user clicks on submit, all the data from the input fields is passed to the parent component?

Comment: That is not my question, I can achieve that by putting TodoInput within within Todo_list. Without changing my code structure, can u pass value between components?

Comment: You can't because you need to pass your callback function `addItem` to `TodoInput`. This can only be done from the parent component.

Comment: Maria, I've updated my answer, does it solve your question?

Comment: when you do this.props.something do u call it `pass something` or `receive something`?

Comment: If rendering in your parent you would have: `<TodoInput addItem={this.something) />`, we would say that you are passing `addItem` as a prop to `TodoInput`. Then inside your child (`TodoInput`) you have received `addItem` as a prop so you can invoke it in the following way: `this.props.addItem('Flower the plants')`.

Comment: Maria, would you like me to add anything to the answer, or does it answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

There is probably cleaned way to do this, but you can do something like this

```
var Todo_list = React.createClass({

  render() {
    return (
    <div>
       {this.props.items.map (i => <div>{i}</div>)}
     </div>
    );
  }
});

var TodoInput = React.createClass({
  getInitialState(){
    return { 
       inputValue: "",
       items: []
    }
  },

  addItem: function(){
    this.setState({ 
        items: this.state.items.concat([this.state.inputValue])
    })

  },

  onChange: function(event){
    this.setState({inputValue: event.target.value})
  },

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
           <input type="text" onChange={this.onChange}/>
           <button onClick={this.addItem}>Add</button>
           <Todo_list items={this.state.items} />
        </div>
    );
  }
});



ReactDOM.render(<TodoInput />, document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nc84n7px/7/)

Comment: Must I put Todo_list component within TodoInput?

Comment: and the concat is for? I don't get the concat part, can't I assigned the new value straight to items?

Comment: I updated jsfiddle. You can do it without concat. If this isn't what you want, you need than to use redux.